# JavaFX - update label values from other thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2

Helo guys!
I am new to JavaFX. I am writing really small application which simulates working of printer. Simulation is running on special thread called PrintingProcess (this process is doing only one thing - waits given time and then increment counter). I need to send this value to window, where labels should show how many pages was "printed". Is any way to do it? So far I wrote small singleton class to hold value.

[edit] I solved it using tasks :) thanks for help

Comment: Show us what you have written so that we may see where your understanding is at, as well as what you have tried vs. what you have not. Any details you can give about your question will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Task.updateProgress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress-double-double-) method. Call it to specify the current percentage of pages printed. Override `Task.call` to perform the action which needs to run in another thread. This method **should never manipulate a JavaFX component**. You can then oerride methods such as `Task.succeeded` to implement the behaviour of your UI when the print job is over. Look at the doc of this class to fully take advantage of it.

Comment: [`Task::getProgress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#getProgress--) is `public final`, you can't override it.

Comment: Mmm true, I answered on the basis of my memories of a JavaFX UI I once wrote. I'm going to fix this as soon as I find the right method to override. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        textLabel.setText(yourValue);
    }
});
```

The example above is quite simple. You ask JavaFX a runnable as soon as it can. I don't know how that works exactly but that's the way to change UI components from a non-JavaFX thread.

You could pass textLabel variable to any thread with a custom class or a new anonymous thread.

EDIT:
I find Dici's answer more appropriate for your application. I wouldn't recommend putting this code in any loop incase you may still use this.

Comment: That would work, but is more fitted to small tasks as opposed to long jobs. To me, a potentially massive print job should be implemented as a `Task`. Apart from this, your proposition works. Why ? Because it ensures your `Runnable` will *eventually* get executed on the JavaFX application thread, with no guarantee of *when* it will get executed

Comment: I agree on that @Dici